# In C++, coding for Arduino, how can I save a function to a variable and call it later via the variable?

Tags: c++, function, variables, arduino

I want to save a function I've made to a string variable and call it later via the variable - something like this:

```
String hello = "helloWorld();";

void loop()
{
    hello;
}

void helloWorld()
{
    //does functional things...
}
```

This is a super basic idea of what I want to make happen.
I'm making a game and want a certain function (different every time) to be stored in a variable to be played back later.

Comment: Use a function pointer?

Comment: It's not possible to use contents of strings as code.You can on the other hand *map* a string to a function using pointers. Or if all you need is to just call a function, save a *pointer* to the function instead, which can then be used as any other function.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a really basic example of how you'd do this please?

Comment: Really simple is to avoid such constructs. If you need *basic* help, just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

To declare a function pointer, you need to know its signature.

If your function `helloWorld` does not take parameters and returns nothing (void
), a variable to store that could be defined as

```
void (*myFunc)() = helloWorld;

void loop()
{
   myFunc();
}
```

The only Arduino specific is that *usually* the required function declaration is done for you secretly behind the scenes.